# What is wrong with this simple vim function?

Tags: function, vim, call

Please have a look to the below vim function which I written in my `/.gvimrc` file.
The function id for deleting the "n" number of last characters in each line from the range of lines specified by "start_line" and "end_line".

```
function RLNC (n, start_line, end_line)
    execute . a:start_line . "," . a:end_line . "s/.\{" . a:n . "}$//"
endfunction
```

but when I make the same as a function and call it in the vim

```
:call RLNC(3, 128, 203)
```

This is the actual operation I am doing here

```
:start_line,end_lines/.\{n}$//
```

This is nothing but

```
:128,203s/.\{3}$//
```

Please help me to find what is going wrong..?

its is giving errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is:

```
E15: Invalid expression: . a:start_line . "," . a:end_line . "s/.\{" . a:n . "}$//"
```

So, the first period is suspect. The `:execute` command takes (one or multiple) expressions. String concatenation via `.` is only done *between* strings, not at the beginning.

Just leave off the first `.`:

```
execute a:start_line . "," . a:end_line . "s/.\{" . a:n . "}$//"
```

The manual concatenation is tedious. Better use `printf()`:

```
execute printf("%d,%ds/.\{%d}$//", a:start_line, a:end_line, a:n)
```

The next problem is that inside double quotes, the backslash must be escaped (doubled). Better use single quotes:

```
execute printf('%d,%ds/.\{%d}$//', a:start_line, a:end_line, a:n)
```

Finally, Vim has a special syntax to pass a range to a function. See `:help function-range-example`. You do not need to use this, but it makes the invocation more natural:

```
:128,203call RLNC(3)
```

However, I would probably go ahead and define a custom command wrapping the function.

```
:command! -range -nargs=1 RLNC call RLNC(<args>, <line1>, <line2>)
```

If your function isn't actually more complex, we can now inline this and get rid of the function altogether:

```
:command! -range -nargs=1 RLNC execute printf('%d,%ds/.\{%d}$//', <line1>, <line2>, <args>)
```

(Note that without a function, the last search pattern gets clobbered.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your reply, I am new to vim function and all. So I don't know much about the "`:command!`" and all. So I put it as function in the /.gvimrc file like below :

```
function RLNC (start_line, end_line, n)
  if (a:start_line <= a:end_line)
    execute printf(':%d,%ds/.\{%d}$//', a:start_line, a:end_line, a:n)
  else
    execute printf('Start line %d is more than End line %d ', a:start_line, a:end_line)
  endif
endfunction
```

and its working fine when I use the `:call RLNC(128, 203, 3)` in my gvim files.

Thanks You